# Перенос строк не происходит

Tags: javascript, dom

По нажатию на кнопку каждой строке, которая заканчивается на точку, должен добавляться перенос строки 
 и в DOM-e все строки с точкой на конце должны начинаться с новой строки. У меня не работает почему-то. 
 присваивается, но перенос строк не наблюдается.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 let text = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
 let str = text.split(' ');
 for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   if(str[i].includes('.')) {
     str[i] += '<br>';
    }
  }
  return str.join(' ');
})
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nemo doloremque aspernatur, esse sed minima? Officia dolorum, cumque non architecto quibusdam ex. Aut, nobis neque laboriosam suscipit quibusdam enim, fugiat!</p>
<button id="button">Press me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что нужен не return, а перезапись текста в абзаце:

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 let text = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
 let str = text.split(' ');
 for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   if(str[i].includes('.')) {
     str[i] += '<br>';
    }
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = str.join(' ');
})
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nemo doloremque aspernatur, esse sed minima? Officia dolorum, cumque non architecto quibusdam ex. Aut, nobis neque laboriosam suscipit quibusdam enim, fugiat!</p>
<button id="button">Press me</button>
```